# The data reader is incompatible with the specified Field

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display some data from two tables: Category and Transactions. 
My error is:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'GestaoFinanceiraModel.Category'. A member of the type, 'id_Category', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

And my code is this:

```
var dbCategories = db.Category.SqlQuery("select Cat.name, isnull(Tr.Soma, 0) from Category cat left join (select category, sum(amout) as soma from Transactions where month(date)='11' group by category) tr ON cat.id_Category=Tr.category order by cat.name").ToList();
```

When i run this sql statement on sql server this return:

```
id_Category is_active   name    budget  is_budget_active    alert
1   1   testeCat    0   0   1
2   1   teste2  0   0   1
3   1   teste3  0   0   1
4   1   teste4  0   0   1
5   1   teste5  0   0   1
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The error says it all: ON cat.id_Category=Tr.category
The names should be both id_Category.

Comment: The names in both columns should be id_category? Cant have in one column id_category and in the other category?!

Comment: @User8889 i have change both to id_category, but i still get the same error

Comment: I'm guessing your trying to display id_category then? Your code SQL doesn't appear to match the output from the server. Your select statement only has two columns.